# XMLHttpRequest to string

Tags: javascript, xml-serialization, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to make a function that sends an `XMLHttpRequest` and return a string with the contents of the response, but it always returns `null`. How do I fix this?

Code:

```
function getPage() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET','page.php',false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    if ($.browser.msie) return xmlDoc.xml;
    else return (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc);
}
```

Comment: Question 1: What browser are you using?  There are two different code paths.
Question 2: Since it seems you're using JQuery, why not use $.get()?

Comment: I use $.ajax() in jQuery because it gives more options.  Then you can just have a listener for success, completed, and error and see what your problem is.

Comment: I am using jQuery. Actually, I could have just used `xmlhttp.responseText` instead of `xmlhttp.responseXML`.

Is `$.get()` asynchronous?

Comment: xmlhttp.responseText should always return the contents of the response, while xmlhttp.responseXML will only return if the response is xml.  Try logging responseText to see with the response actually is; it could be that its not xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Internet Explorer, at least, then you may have a null response because the [ContentType header](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1521/4.htm) in the response is missing or incorrect.  Quoting Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the responseXML property:

> If the ... Multipurpose Internet Mail
>   Extension (MIME) type was not
>   correctly set to one of the supported
>   MIME types ... then responseXML will
>   be empty.
>
> The supported MIME types for MSXML 6.0
>   are: "text/xml", "application/xml" or
>   anything that ends with "+xml", for
>   example "application/rss+xml".
>
> The supported MIME types for versions
>   prior to MSXML 6.0 are: "text/xml",
>   "application/xml".