# Split not working on array

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using following code but the split  is not being performed and the code below the split command is not executing . Some how it looks that split command is halting or either not working . The string temp which is returned is "1,2,3,4,5-9,6,5" . Note : I have already initialzed a blank variable temp so no need to initialize it again in this function i guess.

```js
function showUser(str) {
 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        temp=[xmlhttp.responseText];
  
        var temp2 = temp.split("-");
        myData=temp2[0];
        window.alert(myData);
        myLabels=temp2[1];
        net();
  
    }
        
    xmlhttp.open("GET","new.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  
}
```

Comment: what does the alert show??

Comment: Make sure that the `temp` variable contain what you want.

Comment: @psylogic the alert does not prompt . The code below split is not executing.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I have debugged the temp string , it is same as i posted in my question

Comment: So it should work see the answer bellow.

Comment: Why are you splitting an array?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki The fiddle is working fine but in my problem even the code below the split is not being executed

Comment: @torazaburo need to separate data and label which are in response string  attached by "-"

Comment: Arrays do not have a split function. Strings do. Try `temp = xmlhttp.responseText;`. You will see a console error message, did you check?

Comment: @torazaburo its working now I was using a split function on array as well . Thanks alot helped me

Comment: @phpnet should you be checking the response after the GET rather than before? Similar code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524615/xmlhttprequest-to-string

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the string split in javascript. Take a look at this:

```
var temp = '1,2,3,4,5-9,6,5';
var temp2 = temp.split("-");
myData=temp2[0];
window.alert(myData);
myData2=temp2[1];
window.alert(myData2);
```

<kbd>[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/z8aaqh6v/)</kbd>

Try debugging if `temp` variable's value is correct.

Comment: I have debugged it . Its the same value which i posted in my question . But it not working yet , and the code below is also not executing

Comment: The fiddle in my example is also not working? What browser?